# genymotion chrome doesn't work with charles, getting error "Failed to connect to external proxy"

Tags: genymotion, charles-proxy

I'm using Charles 4.2.6 on Mac 10.13.5 and genymotion emulator

When I tried to open a website on chrome browser, getting error "Failed to connect to external proxy"

I've external proxy enabled 127.0.0.1  8081

please refer to attached screen shot, any thoughts how to fix this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charles acts as a proxy between your device and the Internet, something like this:

Device → Charles → Internet

From what I understand, by setting an external proxy in Charles, you actually tell it that your setup is something like this:

Device → Charles → Another proxy → Internet

Unless you actually need a real proxy to access the Internet, you should be fine by unchecking this "Use external proxy servers" option.

Comment: Thanks for info, but still I can't open google.com . I've disabled "External Proxy Setting" in charles but still get error in chrome as "Name lookup failed for remote host".  The actual exception reported was java.net.UnknownHostException: google.com

Comment: Seems like if you didn't have Internet connection. Could it be any firewall or antivirus software blocking Charles' way out?